# Encountering variable error

Tags: trigger

This is the code I have written and it returns an error saying the prRec variable does not exist. Can someone tell me why its doing this?

```
 public class ProductionRequestTriggerHandler {
    public static void onBeforeInsertUpdate(List<Production_Request__c> prList) {   
    String status;
        List<Merchandise__c> merchList = new List<Merchandise__c>();
        List<String> merchIdList = new List<String>();
            for(Production_Request__c prRec : prList) {
            merchIdList.add(prRec.Merchandise__c);
        }
        List<String> merchandiseIdList = new List<String>();
        Map <String, String> prMap = new Map <String, String>();
        Map <String, String> productionRequestMap = new Map <String, String>();
        
        for (Production_Request__c prRec : prList); {
            merchIdList.add(prRec.Merchandise__c);
            prMap.put(prRec.Merchandise__c, prRec.Status__c);
            productionRequestMap.put(prRec.Merchandise__c, prRec.Id);
        }
        
        for(Merchandise__c merchRec : [SELECT Id, Name,Status__c FROM Merchandise__c WHERE Id IN :merchIdList]) {
            if (prMap.containsKey(merchRec.Id)){
                switch on prMap.get(merchRec.Id) {
                    when 'New' {
                        status = 'Goods Requested';
                    }
                    when 'Approved'{
                        status = 'Production Approved';
                    }
                    when 'In Progress' {
                        status = 'In Production';
                    }
                    when 'Completed' {
                        status = 'Available';
                        if (productionRequestMap.containsKey(merchRec.Id)) {
                            updateRelatedPurchaseRequest(productionRequestMap.get(merchRec.Id));
                        }
                    }
                }
                merchRec.Status__c = status;
                merchList.add(merchRec);
            }
        }
        if(!merchList.isEmpty()){
            update merchList;
        }
    }
    public static void updateRelatedPurchaseRequest(String productionRequestId) {
        List<Purchase_Request__c> purchaseRequestList = new List<Purchase_Request__c>();
        for (Purchase_Request__c prRec : [SELECT Id, Name, Production_Request__c, Status__c, Closed__c FROM Purchase_Request__c WHERE Production_Request__c AN Status__c]) {
            prRec.status__c = 'Produced';
            prRec.Closed__c = true;
            purchaseRequestList.add(prRec);
        }
        if(!purchaseRequestList.isEmpty()){
            update purchaseRequestList;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm in which line of code you are getting this error

Comment: In the below line there was semicolun `;` for the `FOR` loop. can you remove it and try to save the code . `for (Production_Request__c prRec : prList); `

Comment: It worked. I overlooked it apparently. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment. There was extra semicolon `;` for the `For` loop in the below line.

```
for (Production_Request__c prRec : prList);
```

Can you remove that and try to save it.

```
for (Production_Request__c prRec : prList)
```